# Jquery detect begin scroll on element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a big webpage, that has a lot of `<div>` elements. I want to detect when the scroll detects that element. The thing is that I have no id. I tried to do this:

```
$('#hexagon').scroll(function() {

            alert("hi");
            var currY = $(this).scrollTop();
            var postHeight = $(this).height();
            var scrollHeight = $('#path1').height();
            // Current percentual position
            var scrollPercent = (currY / (scrollHeight - postHeight)) * 100;


            triangle.style.strokeDashoffset = scollPercent;
});
```

It doesn't display the alert box. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: you lost me at "when the scroll detects that element the thing is".. maybe try adding some punctuation to make your question coherent.

Comment: i just cant enter the function, the code seems correct what am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var hexagon = $('#hexagon').position().top;
    if($(window).scrollTop() > hexagon) {
        alert('scroll');
    }; 
});
```